# How to find all `td` of `tr` parent tag which have `class="accordion-toggle main-row"' in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have multiple `tr` tag whith different `class` like this:

```
<tr class="accordion-toggle main-row" data-parent="#OrderPackages" data-target=".packageDetails1" data-toggle="collapse" id="package1">
<td><p>01629046</p></td><td><p><a href="https://www.zaubacorp.com/director/SHARMISTHA-HANSRAJ-KAJARIA/01629046"> SHARMISTHA HANSRAJ KAJARIA</a></p>
</td><td><p>Director</p></td>
<td><p>01 November 2012</p></td>
<td><p><a href="javascript:">View other directorships</a></p></td></tr>
```

I want to extract all text of `td.p` if its parent `tr` tag has class="accordion-toggle main-row".

```
<tr class="row text-good" data-parent="#OrderPackages" data-
target=".packageDetails1" data-toggle="collapse" id="package1">
 <td><p>01629046</p></td><td><p><a                          
href="https://www.zaubacorp.com/director/SHARMISTHA-HANSRAJ-KAJARIA/01629046"> SHARMISTHA HANSRAJ KAJARIA</a></p>
</td><td><p>Director</p></td>
<td><p>01 November 2012</p></td>
<td><p><a href="javascript:">View other directorships</a></p></td></tr>
```

**Update:** Here both class are sequentially dependent on each other - like get info from second class and append to as `Dictionary` to Info received using first class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

trs = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : 'accordion-toggle main-row'})
trs.append(soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : 'row text-good'}))

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        print(td.p.text)
```

---

Condition for checking `tr` class during iteration:

```
if(' '.join(tr.get('class') == 'YOUR_CLASS'):
     #Do something
```

`tag.get()` returns list instead of string so you have to join separated class.

Comment: I have to use two class of tr - "accordion-toggle main-row" and "row text-good". First class is used to get different info and second class is used to get other info.

Comment: Is there any way to check class of current tag being iterated in your code like this - 
```if tr.hasClass('thisClass'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        print(td.p.text)
```

Comment: Updated answer to include second class (if you have more classes to include then it's better to use one line with regex rather than append. Yes you can check class during iteration but why don't you want to find them all at once?

Comment: How can I check class during iteration? I am avoiding finding all at once as both classes are sequencially related - and more like dependent on each other. E.g. Get Info from second class and append it to as dictionary to info received from first class.

Comment: Included condition in the answer